# ipad portrait not zooming out to the right sized

Tags: ipad, zooming, portrait

When I look at my website on ipad peek portrait, it does not zoom out the appropriate size.  It may be that my design does not allow for enough fluidity. I am confusing, however because it did seem to work at some point.

Please see http://www.nogginusers.com/libermanproperties/libermanproperties.html

and a standard media stylesheet for ipad portrait